# Match number of chars between quotes with Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Suppose my data is the following

```
Hello { "I have {g{t{" braces { between "{" { quotes{  "{{"
```

How can I match the { symbol that is only between the quotes? I am trying to extract the number of occurrences of a specified character only between quotes. Any ideas? The sample should match 6 braces

Comment: `str.match(/"(?:[^\\"]+|\\.)*"/g).join().split('{').length-1;`

Comment: Why do people insist on providing answers in comments?  You don't build any rep that way....

Answer (score 6):

```
var nb = str.split('"').filter(function(_,i){return i%2}).join('')
     .split('{').length - 1;
```

Comment: What about using regular expressions?

Comment: +1 for `.filter(function(_,i){return i%2})` :-) Oh and `.split('{').length` is cute as well :-)

Comment: @MehdiKaramosly regexes are like jQuery : I use them when they make the code faster, simpler or more readable. Here it's straightforward without them.

Answer (score 0):

Where `s` is your string

```
s.match(/"(.+?)"/g).reduce(function(p,c) {return p + (c.match(/{/g)||[]).length;}, 0);
```

Since some people find regular expressions intimidating, I thought it might help to go step by step through how this works. :)

- The first regular expression `/"(.+?)"/g` gives you an array of all quoted strings in the original string.

  - The starting and ending `/` and `/` are to regular expressions as quote marks are to strings. The `g` incidicates that this is a global search—we want all the quoted strings, not just the first one.
  - `"` represents a quote mark before and after the string to be matched
  - `.` means any character
  - `+?` is an idiom that means everything up to the next character in the regular expression; in other words a *non-greedy* match. If we used `*` here instead of `+?` we would find only one big quoted string between the very first and very last `"`, with all the other `"`s contained within it!
  - Then we put in parentheses what we want the match function to actually return to us. In this case it's everything inside the quote marks, leaving the quote marks out.
- The second regular expression `/{/g` counts your `{` characters. By using `||[]` we ensure that we get a return value of `0` even if there are no brace characters found.
- The easiest way to sum these without needing to loop is to use `reduce`, which we feed an initial value of `0`.